# Exchange rate prediction for shopping

Tags: foreign-exchange

I don't know how appropriate this question is, but I need your help. I'm in Turkey right now, I'm going to buy dollar-based products, but Turkey's exchange rate system is very volatile and it is always on the rise. and I don't know what to do, I don't know if it's better to buy now or wait. I'm scared of if dolar become more cheaper after i make shopping.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because personal finance is off-topic here. You could try googling "exchange rate futures".

Answer (score 1):

There is no good answer for this question, because there is no way to predict how rates will move with any accuracy.  It also requires a thorough understanding of the factors making Turkey's currency so volatile, and I doubt you'll find such an expert here.
The best answer is to use your best judgment and be ready to live with whatever the outcome is.